# Grid Row Total issue in exported CSV - Magento 2

Tags: grid, export, magento2

I am facing an issue in My custom grid. I have added 'Export to CSV' in Grid and it is working fine.

Issue is I have added a row total in grid but in Exported CSV, total is actually the total of all rows rather then the total of filtered rows.

I am using a below code to add the Total row for a specific column. This code is working in Grid Block but not working in GridExport Block.

```
protected function _afterLoadCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->getCollection();

    $salesTotal = 0;

    foreach ($collection as $rowData) {
        $salesTotal += (float)$rowData->getPrice() * (float)$rowData->getQuantity();
    }
    $this->setTotals(new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        array( 'subtotal'=>$salesTotal )
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

It seems that, _afterLoadCollection() never call in GridExport Block although both Blocks are extending the same class as

```
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended { ... }
class GridExport extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended { ... }
```

Grid and CSV samples are attached for reference.

**Grid**
[image]
**CSV**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue. There are basically 2 functions in Extended Grid Block

```
namespace Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
// other stuff
class Extended extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ExportInterface
{
    // other code
    public function getCsvFile()
    {
        // doesn't call _afterLoadCollection() function
    }

    // other code
    public function getCsv()
    {
         $csv = '';
         $this->_isExport = true;
         $this->_prepareGrid();
         $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->limit();
         $this->getCollection()->setPageSize(0);
         $this->getCollection()->load();
         $this->_afterLoadCollection(); // That I needed
         // ...
     }
     // ...
}
```

So I have used getCsv() function in my Controller as:

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

    $fileName = 'Referral_'. date('Y-m-d h:i:s') . '.csv';
    $exportBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()
        ->createBlock(
            'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Referrals\GridExport'
        );
    return $this->_fileFactory->create(
        $fileName,
        $exportBlock->getCsv(), // this fucntion
        DirectoryList::VAR_DIR
    );
}
```

Although, I am not sure what's the difference between getCsv() and getCsvFile()